# jquery fluid_dg slider set set slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [fluid_dg](http://www.css-jquery-design.com/jquery-responsive-slider-fluid-slideshow-plugin-fluid_dg-responsive_dg/) slider for image sliding. It is working as expected. 
Once loaded, It starts the slider from the first image. But I want to start the slider from a specific image. I go through the documentation. But no luck.

Is there any custom way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fluid_dg` slider loads the image from an array. To start the slider from a specific image, simplest way is to reordered the imageList and loaded the required image as the first image in the array.

Example:

> imageList = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"]

To start the slider from the image `3.jpg`, 
Reorder the `imageList` like this

> imageList = ["3.jpg", "4.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg"]

Since the slider is running in a circular form image reordering will not affect the image sequence.